# I'm getting a transient failure with MySQL and MariaDB

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, minimal-apis, asp.net-core-7.0

I am working on a simple Web API that uses MySQL as database. It's pretty basic:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder
    .Services
    .AddDbContext<RequestContext>(options =>
    {
        options
            .UseMySql(builder.Configuration["ConnectionStrings:Requests"], new MySqlServerVersion(new Version()))
            .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .EnableDetailedErrors();
    })
var app = builder.Build();
app
    .UseHsts()
    .UseHttpsRedirection()
    .UseDefaultFiles();
app
    .Use(async (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
    {
        context.Request.EnableBuffering();
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        await next();
        var db = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<RequestContext>();
        string headers = string.Join("\r\n", context.Request.Headers.Select(r => $"{r.Key} = {r.Value}"));
        string body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        var rec = new Request()
        {
            Host = context.Request.Host.Host,
            Port = context.Connection.LocalPort,
            IPAddress = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress ?? IPAddress.None,
            Url = context.Request.GetEncodedUrl(),
            Method = context.Request.Method,
            Headers = headers,
            Body = body,
            Valid = context.Response.StatusCode < 400
        };
        db.Requests.Add(rec);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    });
... (Several endpoints after this.) ...
```

The idea is simple. This is a middleware method that writes all requests to the database with either "Valid" or "Invalid", depending on the status code in the response. This API might receive about 10 requests per hour so it should work. Except it doesn't...

```
MySqlException: Connect Timeout expired.
MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.CreateSessionAsync(ConnectionPool pool, int startTickCount, Activity activity, Nullable<IOBehavior> ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlConnection.cs
System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask<TResult>.get_Result()
MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.OpenAsync(Nullable<IOBehavior> ioBehavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in MySqlConnection.cs
MySqlConnector.MySqlConnection.Open() in MySqlConnection.cs
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(bool errorsExpected)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(bool errorsExpected)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlRelationalConnection.Open(bool errorsExpected)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlDatabaseCreator+<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass12_0<TState, TResult>.<Execute>b__0(DbContext _, TState s)
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.Internal.MySqlExecutionStrategy.Execute<TState, TResult>(TState state, Func<DbContext, TState, TResult> operation, Func<DbContext, TState, ExecutionResult<TResult>> verifySucceeded)
```

That is one of the exceptions I get, if I get any. Sometimes, the action performs but nothing gets written to the database. And sometimes I get this timeout which also includes this line:

```
InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
```

The problem is that I use the same database in a console application, where it runs perfectly well. And fast. But in this web API, using the same connection string, I just end up with this exception or with no records written. And now I'm stumped.
I'm doing something wrong here but this request logging is a requirement for this project. Even more annoying, this project was first developed in .NET 6.0 with EF6 and Pomelo 6.0.2. But it needs to move to .NET 7 and thus I use EF7 and Pomelo 7.0.0-silver.1 and it keeps failing over and over again. It's becoming so bad that I'm seriously considering moving back to .NET 6.0 with the older EF6 framework.
The errors seem to be located in the Pomelo package and in the MySqlConnector package which Pomelo needs.
Btw, adding `options => options.EnableRetryOnFailure()` to the UseMySql() just makes it crash slower. And I don't know why the performance in my Web API is so bad while I have no problems in my console application...

Comment: The first line of the error message is "MySqlException: Connect Timeout expired." - my understanding is that you do not believe the connection to the database is a problem, but what is the exact difference in topology between "run in a console" and this web app? Do you run both from the same computer/instance/server? Do you use docker or something similar?

Comment: You might get more help posting this issue at https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, particularly if it seems to be a regression from 6.0.2 to 7.0.0-silver.1. I'm not sure that the Pomelo devs check SO frequently.

Comment: @petrch They're both run from the same computer, using the same DBContext and the same connection string. The Api runs in IIS Express and that shows it down for some reason. But when I replace the database with SQLite, the performance is lightning fast in IIS. So my project now works with SQLite, but it needs to use MySQL instead.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger Posting the issue at GitHub is an option, but would need a code example that others can use to reproduce the error. Haven't had the time to do that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only getting a few requests per hour, you may as well do

```
connect
perform the inserts and any related actions
disconnect
```

A guess:  the connection is timing out, but the package obscures that error with a more cryptic "EnableRetryOnFailure".  Auto-reconnect can lead to screwed-up transactions.